# How to save a matching regex's value to a variable in one line of perl?

Tags: regex, perl

I'm sure there is a very simple way to do this, but whenever I search for examples, I get the two step method. Here is what I typically do:

```
$data =~ m/(my_query)/;
$result = $1;
```

I want to set $result in the same line as the regex and never use $1. Thanks!

Comment: What's wrong with using `$1`?

Comment: I really like using $1 when it serves a purpose, like a situation where I grab several things from a query:   $data =~ m/^([A-Z])\t([0-9])/;  $HASH{$1} = $2;     <-- this is how I wanna use my $1's and $2's!

Comment: Or you could use descriptive variable names for the 'several things', especially if you'll refer to them multiple times: `if (my ($server, $capacity) = $data =~ m/^([A-Z])\t([0-9])/)) { $totals{$server} = $capacity; log("$server at $capacity capacity");}`

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I like the variable reassignment

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
my($result) = ($data =~ m/(my_query)/);
```

As noted in a comment, the `my($result)` needs the parentheses to provide an array context for the result of the match. In an array context, you get the `$1` etc allocated to the array. You could use `@result = ($data =~ m/(my_query)/);`; you could omit the `my` but you would need to keep the parentheses; you could subscript the array using `$result = ($data =~ m/(my_query)/)[0];` (thanks [ysth](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17389/ysth)). The key words here are 'array context'.

Examples:

```
$ perl -e '$data="abcdef";my($result)=($data =~ m/(cde)/); print "$result\n"'
cde
$ perl -e '$data="abcdef";  ($result)=($data =~ m/(cde)/); print "$result\n"'
cde
$ perl -e '$data="abcdef";   @result =($data =~ m/(cde)/); print "$result[0]\n"'
cde
$ perl -e '$data="abcdef";   $result =($data =~ m/(cde)/)[0]; print "$result\n"'
cde
$
```

Comment: haha, so easy, I just never got the syntax correct. I'll accept this after the time limit ends. Also, is the "my" necessary here, and if so what is it used for?

Comment: The `my($result)` needs the parentheses to provide an array context for the result of the match.  In an array context, you get the $1 etc allocated to the array parts.  You could use `@result = ($data =~ m/(my_query)/);`; you could omit the `my` but you would need to keep the parentheses.  The key words here are 'array context'.

Comment: or you could do (with or without my) `$result = ($data=~/(my_query)/)[0];`

Comment: Yeah, you probably could used a subscript; the subscript gives the regex an array context, and the subscript converts that to a scalar context.

Answer (score 2):

You didn't specify what problem you want to avoid, but there is definitely one to avoid. The following code assigns something unknown to `$result` when the pattern doesn't match:

```
$data =~ /(my_query)/;
my $result = $1;
```

You could use a conditional to assign something useful to `$result` when the pattern doesn't match

```
my $result = $data =~ /(my_query)/ ? $1 : undef;
```

Or you could take advantage of the fact that `m//` in list context returns what it captured.

```
my ($result) = $data =~ /(my_query)/;
```

Comment: Good point about the exception handling, my favorite method is your suggestion of " ? $1 : undef;", which is what I will incorporate into my scripts for now on. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
$data="abcde";
$data =~ s/(cde)/$result=$1/e;
```